# DLL dependency not getting copied issue

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm using VS2015 and have two projects where the child project references DapperExtensions (X--> Y--> DapperExtensions).
Now DapperExtensions seems to have implicit dependency on Dapper.
When I try and use code from Y in X, I get an error regarding Dapper.dll missing.
It seems with dlls being copied to project X debug folder, only DapperExtensions.dll is getting copied but Dapper.dll isn't. 
Presumably related to the direct dependency issue identified in stackoverflow already :
[Dll not copying to bin folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842383/dll-not-copying-to-bin-folder)

So I created some dummy code to reference an arbitrary reference from Dapper but this doesn't seem to lead to the DLL getting copied as per existing suggestions in stackoverflow:

```
public static void Dummy()
        {
            Action<Type> noop = _ => { };
            var dummy = typeof(Dapper.DbString);
            noop(dummy);
        }
```

The only thing I guess left is to add dappper dll reference directly to ProjectX which I really want to avoid.
Any ideas why the dummy reference thing doesn't work?

Comment: Are you using the "Build" command or the "Rebuild All" command? Have you tried to "Clean" your solution?

Comment: @NoelWidmer Yes have tried rebuild, clean/build and still no difference

Comment: Alright, dll issues are often related to their version. If you reference assembly v1 and something is expecting assembly v2 it won't work. Is this a compile or a execution time issue? Maybe you want to try to figure out some version infos about your assemblies in the meantime.

Comment: @NoelWidmer Not sure if it's a version related issue or not as I'm just using the latest version of DapperExtensions from nuget, which has a dependency with Dapper (as expected!)

Comment: @NoelWidmer In addition, this is a run time issue as it compiles fine.